# Deno Uncaught Error: No such host is known. (os error 11001)

Tags: mongodb, deno

I tried to connect the `MongoDB Atlas` to my Deno Application using https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.21.2  framework. I tried the below code to run my application. but I get an error  `No such host is known. (os error 11001)` What went wrong here

> Error

```
error: Uncaught Error: No such host is known. (os error 11001)
    at unwrapResponse (rt\10_dispatch_json.js:24:13)
    at sendAsync (rt\10_dispatch_json.js:75:12)
    at async Object.connect (rt\30_net.js:221:13)
    at async MongoClient.connect (client.ts:41:14)
    at async mongodb.ts:33:1
```

> Mongodb.ts File

```
import { MongoClient } from "https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.21.0/mod.ts";
    
    const client1 = new MongoClient();
    await client1.connect("mongodb+srv://user1:MYPASSWORD@cluster0.hmdnu.mongodb.net/TestingDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
    
    const db = client1.database("TestingDB");
    
    export default db;
```

I used this command to run my server

```
deno run --allow-net --allow-write --allow-read  --allow-plugin --unstable server.ts
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hhdhydffKKE

Comment: Thank you a lot I tried to fix this issue because of you I fixed this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed this using https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hhdhydffKKE this video reference

Follow these steps to fix this

```
    import { MongoClient } from "https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.21.0/mod.ts";
    
    const client1 = new MongoClient();
    
    await client.connect({
    db: "<db>",
    tls: true,
    servers: [
      { 
        host: "<host>",
        port: 27017,
      },
    ],
    credential: {
      username: "<user>",
      password: "<password>",
      db: "<db>",
      mechanism: "SCRAM-SHA-1",
    },
  });
    
 const db = client1.database("TestingDB");
    
 export default db;
```

> This is not mentions in the document, but this will help to fix the issue

> `<db>` is the database name, you can get the database name by following these steps

Step-1
[image: step -1]

Step-2
[image: step-2]

> To find the `<host>` follow these steps

Step -1
[image]

Step -2
[image]

Step -3
[image]

Comment: I solved it only by finding the primary URL, from the rest, I connect with the string directly without using the object. Thanks for the reply.